# How to parse String to Date in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I am having problem while parsing String to Date format. I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase and convert it to Date type.

I have used SimpleDateFormat to parse and its working fine normally. The problem arise only when I try to parse data from Firebase.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);
       calT = Calendar.getInstance();
       calD = Calendar.getInstance();
       try {
           today = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.getDefault()).parse(stoday); // WORKING FINE
       } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                       for (DataSnapshot activitySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                           ActivityData activityData = activitySnapshot.getValue(ActivityData.class);
                           DateOfEvent = String.valueOf(activitySnapshot.child("dateOfEvent").getValue());
                           try {
                               date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy",Locale.getDefault()).parse(DateOfEvent); //RETURNS NULL
                           } catch (ParseException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
```

I expect the code to return Date, but it returns NULL. Thanks.

Comment: This code may help                             
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date d = dateFormat.parse(datestring)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Debug value of your date]You need to provide the format in which you are receiving date from firebase . 
In order to convert string to date use the below function :

```
public static Date getDateFromString(String dateText, String fromFormat) {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(dateText);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Just make sure you are passing the correct date format .

Comment: I have set date1= getDateFromString(DateofEvent, "dd-MMM-YY"), but It returns the current date only.

Comment: what exactly is your DateofEvent value?

Comment: "01-Jan-62" is my value

Comment: Please check the screen shot

Comment: date1 = getDateFromString(DateOfEvent, "dd-MM-yy");...............In debugger, DateOfEvent: 01-Jan-62, date1 : Sat Jun 22 09:41:11 GMT+05:30 2019